# Localize script not working in ajax

Tags: theme-development, wp-localize-script

I'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: WPURLS is not defined" when I try to use ajax. Have I done something wrong here? Running the localize script after the script.min.js file, is there something else that needs to be added?

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    $stylesheet_cache = get_stylesheet_directory().'/lib/styles/css/main.min.css';

    // Load main css file
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mild-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), filemtime($stylesheet_cache) );
    // Load main js file
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mild-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/assets/scripts/script.min.js', [ 'jquery' ], '1.0.0', true );
    // Load comment script
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    wp_localize_script('scripts',
        'WPURLS',
        array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'site_url' => home_url(),
        )
    );

} );
```

Answer (score 2):

> Running the localize script after the script.min.js file

If that is the script you're trying to localize, which you enqueued using the **script handle** `mild-scripts`, then you also need to use that as the script handle when calling [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/). I.e.

```php
wp_localize_script(
    'mild-scripts', // script handle
    'WPURLS',       // JS object name
    array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'site_url' => home_url(),
    )
);
```